# Абстрактный класс

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

У меня есть некий абстрактный класс, назовем его `Abs`:

```
class Abs
{
protected:
    std::string str;
public:
    Abs(std::string str) : str(str) {}
    virtual void print() const = 0;
};
```

И от него наследуется какой-то класс `Test`:

```
class Test : public Abs
{
public:
    Test(std::string str) : Abs(str) {}
    void print() const override
    {
        std::cout << " str: " << str << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Также я имею класс `DoubleTest`, что хранит два объекта класса `Test`:

```
class DoubleTest
{
private:
    Test a;
    Test b;
public:
    DoubleTest() : a("test1"), b("test2")
    {

    }
    void print() const
    {
        a.print();
        b.print();
    }
};
```

Теперь я создаю указатель на тип абстрактного класса `Abs`:

```
Abs * ptr;
```

И могу выделить память под его наследника - `Test`.
Но я хочу чтобы была возможность выделить память и под тип `DoubleTest`. Понимаю, что для этого `DoubleTest` должен быть наследником класса `Abs`, но не понимаю как это реализовать.

**Вопрос**: Как сделать так, чтобы под указатель `ptr` можно было выделить память типа `DoubleTest`? Т.е., как его нужно правильно унаследовать, чтобы при этом он хранил два `Test'a`?

Глубоко извиняюсь за глупый вопрос. Большое спасибо!

Comment: так же, как и в первом случае, нет? `class DoubleTest
: public Abs`

Comment: А **зачем** вам это нужно? Если вы хотите работать с `DoubleTest` как с `Abs` - наследуйте. Но только раз уж вы использовали композицию - вам точно нужно наследование?...

Comment: @Harry, логично. Тоже думаю, что такая идея бредовая. Спасибо

Comment: @VTT, т.е., Вы предлагаете просто унаследоваться от класса `Abs`, но ничего не выполнять для строки `test`? Сделать в `Abs` конструктор по умолчанию для этого.

Comment: Для какой еще "строки test"? Если хотите, чтобы объект `Abs *` указывал на экземпляр объекта `DoubleTest`, то `DoubleTest` должен наследовать от `Abs`. Вы же правильно написали.

Comment: @VTT, спасибо. Понял :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Abs
{
protected:
    std::string str;
public:
    Abs(std::string str) : str(str) {}
    virtual void print() const = 0;
};    
class Test : public Abs
{
public:
    Test(std::string str) : Abs(str) {}
    void print() const override
    {
        std::cout << " str: " << str << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Теперь вам нужно, чтобы  `DoubleTest`  содержал два экземпляра класса `Test`. Наследуя этот класс, вы получаете класс с одним жкземпляром `Test`. Добавьте туда еще один экземпляр и все...

```
class DoubleTest : public Test
{
private:    
    Test b;
public:
    DoubleTest() : Test("test1"), b("test2"){}
    void print() const override
    {
        Test::print(); //вывод базового
        b.print();      //вывод включаемого
    }
};    

int main() {    
    Abs* ptr = new DoubleTest;
    ptr->print(); 
    //...
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Создаёте дерево классов, где каждый родственный класс под главным находиться. В вашем случае я предлагаю **очень** абстрактный класс.

```
# include <string>
# include <iostream>

class VeryAbs{
public:
virtual void print() const = 0;
};

class Abs:public VeryAbs
{
public:
    Abs(std::string str) : str(str) {}
    virtual void print() const = 0;
protected:
    std::string str;
};

class Test : public Abs
{
public:
    Test(std::string str) : Abs(str) {}
    void print() const override
    {
        std::cout << " str: " << str << std::endl;
    }
};

class DoubleTest:public VeryAbs
{
public:
    DoubleTest() : a("test1"), b("test2")
    {

    }
    virtual void print() const
    {
        a.print();
        b.print();
    }
private:
    Test a;
    Test b;    
};

int main(){
VeryAbs * dt = new  DoubleTest();
dt->print();
}
```